# how to use GET to obtain info from a URL

Tags: php, api, get

I'm a php programmer but I'm new to APIs. 
I would like to run a mysql query to get info from an XML document from madmimi.com. 
documentation from [madmimi.com](https://madmimi.com/developer/lists/get-all-audience-lists) says 
GET http://madmimi.com/audience_lists/lists.xml will return the data I need. I've created a php file and connected to their API using

> require(dirname(**FILE**) . '/MadMimi.class.php');
>
> $mailer = new MadMimi('username', 'password');

but I don't understand how to use GET to connect to the URL and display the XML info? 
What do I need to do?

Comment: [php examples for madmimi](https://madmimi.com/developer/api-client-libraries/example-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All http api interaction is hidden to you behind their library. You can use it's methods to grab objects, like this to lists:

```
$mailer->Lists();
```

There is no complete documentation, but you can read [raw code](https://github.com/madmimi/madmimi-php/blob/master/MadMimi.class.php) to search urls, described in API for finding appreciated methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to get the response from the 3rd party api. Have a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159513/1369567

Based upon the code in answer given at that link, you may need to the code to match your request. E.g:

```
/* Script URL */
$url = 'http://madmimi.com/audience_lists/lists.xml';

/* $_GET Parameters to Send */
$params = array('username' => '*your api username*', 'password' => '*your api password*');
```